# CSS3 анимация до конца независимо от события вызвавшего ее

Tags: css3, css-animation, вёрстка, css

Простой пример: кнопка уменьшается по :active, при помощи заанимированного трансформа scale: http://jsfiddle.net/3gTUX/2/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes reduction {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
    }
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #800080;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -100px;
}
div:hover {
    background: #990099;
}
div:active {
    -webkit-animation: reduction .1s ease 1 forwards;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello, transform</div>
```

Чтобы анимация проигралась до конца в этом примере кнопку нужно держать нажатой, не отпускать кнопку мыши.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможноли сделать так, что бы анимация проигрывалась до конца, даже если пользователь просто быстро кликнул по кнопке?

**UPD:** понятно, что можно JS-ом добавить класс .stand-by, например, и через секунду его снять и на этот класс уже повесить анимацию. Но хотелось бы ограничиться CSS-ом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, без JS нельзя. Как вариант сделайте уменьлшение на хавере, и смену цвета при активе. 
http://jsfiddle.net/3gTUX/5/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes reduction { 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(.8); } }


div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #800080;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -100px;
}

div:hover {
    -webkit-animation: reduction .1s ease 1 forwards;
    background: #990099;
}

div:active {
    -webkit-animation: reduction .1s ease 1 forwards;
    background: #993399;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello, transform</div>
```